# Convexity of the Frobenius norm of the product of two matrices

Tags: matrices, convexity, norms, traces

I have the following function for two matrices ${\bf A}$ and ${\bf B}$:

$f({\bf A}, {\bf B}) = \| {\bf Y - XAB} \|_F^2 = trace\{({\bf Y - XAB)}^T({\bf Y - XAB)}\}$

where matrices ${\bf X}_{n \times p}$ and ${\bf Y}_{n \times q}$ are fixed, and matrices ${\bf A}_{p \times r}$ and ${\bf B}_{r \times q}$ are the variables, with $r<\min(p,q)$. I'd like to know whether this function is convex in *both* ${\bf A}$ and ${\bf B}$. (I am quite sure if either ${\bf A}$ or ${\bf B}$ is fixed, then, $f$ is convex for the other one.)

If it is not convex, can I impose some extra constraints on any of these matrices to make $f$ convex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is convex separately for $A$ or $B$ but is not (in general) for the couple $(A,B)$.

Proof: The Hessian of $f$ in $X,Y$ is the following QUADRATIC form:

$Q(H,K)=2(||XHB+XAK||^2+2trace((XAB)^TXHK))-4trace(Y^TXHK)$.

Then $Q(H,0)=2||XHB||^2$ and $f$ is convex for $A$ (and similarly for $B$) - One must say a little more if there is $H\not=0$ s.t. $XHB=0$ -

The problem is clear when, as Robert wrote above, $Y=0$. Moreover, take $H=A,K=-B$ and assume that $XAB\not=0$. Then $Q(A,-B)=-4trace((XAB)^T(XAB))<0$. Thus $Q$ is not non-negative and $f$ is not convex.

EDIT (answer to Mkl). $H=0$ iff $XHB=(X\bigotimes B^T)(H)=0$ that is $X\bigotimes B^T$ is one to one, or $rank(X\bigotimes B^T)=pr$ (necessarily $pr\leq nq$). Let $(\sigma_i)_{i\leq \alpha},(\tau_j)_{j\leq\beta}$ be the non-zero singular values of $X,B$ where $rank(X)=\alpha,rank(B)=\beta$. The non-zero singular values of $X\bigotimes B^T$ are the $(\sigma_i\tau_j)_{i,j}$. Then the condition is $\alpha\beta=pr$. Note that $\beta\leq r,\alpha\leq p$. Necessarily $\beta=r,\alpha=p$ and then $p\leq n$.

Conclusion: The NSC is: $X,B$ have full rank and $p\leq n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a follow up question. What conditions need to be hold for $X$ and/or $B$ such that $XHB = 0$ iff $H=0$? (For example, for strict convexity for $B$, we need $A^TX^TXA$ to be invertible.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the case $n=q=p=r=1$?  Consider $Y=0$, $X=1$, $(A,B) = (1,0),$ $(1/2, 1/2)$ and $(0,1)$.  Yes, I know you said $r < \min(p,q)$, but you can easily throw in some irrelevant dimensions.